# File not found: trying to append csv data in Stata

Tags: csv, stata

I have some .csv files in the same directory and I am trying to `append` these in Stata. But when I use `append`, Stata cannot find the next file. My code is the following:

```
cd "C:\mydir"
insheet using "file1.csv", clear
append using "file2.csv"
```

With the last line, I obtain the following error:

```
file file2.csv not found
```

I have more expertise with R and I know this procedure is similar to `rbind`.

Comment: `append` is a command, not a function (edited out, but note for future).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `append` a .csv file to a Stata dataset that is produced by `insheet`. Save the .csv files as Stata files, `insheet` the last, and then `append` the Stata ones to that.